# VLCKit: Can't reset VLCMediaPlayer.position to 0 when I stop a video

Tags: swift, macos, libvlc

I have a button that do the following code:

```
thePlayer.stop()
```

where `thePlayer` is my video player using VLCKit.

The `thePlayer.position` doesn't reset to `0` after I pressed that button and I can't set to `0` manually by using `thePlayer.position = 0`, because I didn't change anything. When I print the position, it prints me the value just before it stopped.

Also it seems that `thePlayer.time` following by anything after that is get only value...

I would like to set the value of `thePlayer.position` to `0` so when I press the Play button my slider doesn't jump back quickly to the last position before I stopped and then get back near the beginning.

**EDIT:**

I'm using version 3.1.2 of VLCKit via cocoapods.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you want to stop the media playback. If you want to reset the mediaPlayer's position, you can simply set it manually just how you described without calling `stop()`:

```
    mediaPlayer.position = 0
```

Comment: As I stated in my original post, if I try to do what you suggest me, the value `thePlayer.position` does not change to `0`. Also, if my user use the `stop` button, it needs to set the position of `thePlayer` to `0`, so that if the user wants to watch a new video (or start the video back from the beginning), the position of the slider won't quickly jump back to the middle than back to the current position while the video starts...